# This mysqli_query will not execute

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my code using *OO* style:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles LIMIT 1";
$result=mysqli_query($db, $query) or die("Could Not execute query.");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc()
echo $row;
```

Code using *Procedural*:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles LIMIT 1";
$result=mysqli_query($db, $query) or die("Couldn't execute query.");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo $row;
```

I have tried various different ways of getting this to work and the query never seems to execute.

I am new to `mysqli` from mysql and am struggling with some of the differences.
Apologies if there is an obvious answer to this question.

Any Help much appreciated.

Comment: You're mixing functional and OOP code

Comment: Ok thanks. Which pieces of code are out of place?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM articles LIMIT 1";
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
```

or:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: So the result has to be an object for it to work? Ill give this a try. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your

```
 $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

then  you can have

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM articles LIMIT 1";
$res = $db->query($query);
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```